# How to restore from Time Machine backup

Tags: macos, time-machine

I have two Macbooks. The second one I did a refresh install from a Time Machine backup and kept it backed up for several weeks on that computer.

I'm going back to the first computer and would like to restore it to the state of the second computer.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Follow [these instructions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203981) on your first computer:

> 1. Make sure that your Time Machine backup disk is connected and turned on, then turn on your Mac. [...] [O]pen Migration Assistant, which is in the Utilities folder of your Applications folder. Click Continue in the first Migration Assistant window, then continue to step 2.
> 2. When you're asked how you want to transfer your information, select the option to transfer from a Mac, Time Machine backup, or startup disk. Then click Continue.
> 3. Select your Time Machine backup, then click Continue.
> 4. If you're asked to choose from a list of backups organized by date and time, choose a backup and click Continue.
> 5. Select the information to transfer, then click Continue to start the transfer.